# Implementing a dynamic OAuthBearerServerOptions AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan value from data store

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, token, owin

The context of this post involves ASP.NET Web API 2.2 + OWIN
The environment is a single application with both OWIN server and Web Api.

**Background**:

In the Startup class, one must specify [OAuthBearerServerOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions(v=vs.113).aspx) which is supplied to the [OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthbearerauthenticationprovider(v=vs.113).aspx). These options are created during the start up of the OWIN server. On the [OAuthBearerServerOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions(v=vs.113).aspx), I must specify the [AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserveroptions.accesstokenexpiretimespan(v=vs.113).aspx) so that I can ensure expiry of tokens.

**The Issue**

I must be able to dynamically specify the Expiration time span on a per authentication request basis. I am unsure if this can be done and was wondering:

- Can it be done?
- If yes; at which point could I perform this look up and assignment of the expiration?

Content of start up config:

```
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);


    var container = builder.Build();
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/OAuth"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(**THIS NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC**)),
        Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    //STOP!!!!!!!!
    //DO NOT CHANGE THE ORDER OF THE BELOW app.Use statements!!!!!

    //Token Generation 
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); //this MUST come before oauth registration
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Provider = new BearerProvider()
    });
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container); //this MUST come before UseAutofacWebApi
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);//this MUST come before app.UseWebApi
    app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I started messing with the BearerProvider class (see app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication above for where I use this class) and in specific, the ValidateIdentity method, but wasn't sure if that was the proper point in the auth workflow to set this value. It seemed appropriate, but I seek validation of my position.

```
public class BearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override async Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        await base.RequestToken(context);

        //No token? attempt to retrieve from query string
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
        {
            context.Token = context.Request.Query.Get("access_token");

        }
    }
    public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        //context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc= //SOME DB CALL TO FIND OUT EXPIRE VALUE..IS THIS PROPER?
        return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan will actually change the global value, and affect all requests, that won't work for the original requirement.

The right place is the TokenEndpoint method.

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    ...

    if (someCondition)
    {
        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = GetExpirationDateFromDB();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am no longer on the project at the moment, but if I get to verify, I will do so and update the post with the confirmation and potential answer change.

Comment: I know this answer is getting a bit older now, but this doesn't work for me.  The '.expires' time in the returned token is still the default 20 minutes, regardless of what I set into `ExpiresUtc`.

Comment: @Tom, Are you sure? I just retest and it is still working to me.  Which version of `Microsoft.Owin` are you using, and could you share some code how you use it?

Answer (score 3):

So I was in the wrong spot entirely. What I ended up having to do was to use my custom OAuthorizationServerProvider and in the overridden GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method in that custom class, I was able to set the timeout value by accessing the...

```
context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan
```

property.

```
 <!-- language: c# -->

    public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        {
            public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
            {
               //DO STUFF
               var expireValue=GetTimeOutFromSomeplace();
               context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = expireValue;
               //DO OTHER TOKEN STUFF
            } 
        }
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. You are creating a race condition if multiple client requests are being processed.

Comment: Is that because the updating of the AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan ?

Comment: Exactly.

Say client A comes in and you want it set for 1 hour. GrantResourceOwnerCredentials starts to process it and you change context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan to 1 hour.

Now client B comes in and you want it set for 1 year. It changes context.Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan to 1 year.

Now both client A and B both finally exit GrantResourceOwnerCredentials and both expire in 1 year.

Comment: makes perfect sense. Thank you. Does Dichen's answer above more accurately answer this question? It 'looks' like what I'm after but I haven't been in that project for months (stalled) so I haven't tested it out.

Comment: Yes, his answer will work. I really wish the documentation was better.

Comment: I agree. The documentation is abysmal.